# Saving the value of a Text Area to a text file

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

How to get the text in a Text Area to be saved to a text file when a button is clicked?

I have implemented the GUI and when the `btnContinue` button is clicked I want the content of `txtOrder` to be saved to a text file in notepad.

Comment: Do you know how to write content in a file?

Comment: Do you know how to use the ActionListener?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a pro programmer in Java so pls correct me if I'm wrong, but I would try this:

```
FileWriter fw = null;
try
{
    fw = new FileWriter("Output.txt",true);
    fw.write(txtOrder.getText())
    //textArea.write(fw);
}
catch (IOException ex) 
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally 
    {
       if (fw!=null)
       {  
           fw.close();
       }
    }
```

Comment: more like fw.write(txtOrder.getText())

Comment: @meister_reineke  ok I change it, but it worked for me (I copied the code from my working program and there a push to a button and all what was printed in the Area would get copied in my txt-File) but if yours is better it's ok, I'm always willing to learn^^

Comment: what did you mean with cleaner? should I change it back or left it with your statement from 1. commend?

Comment: @DenisMurphy if it works pls accept the answer to tell other people that this answer was the solution for you (it's a common technique and you should have noticed it by reading the guidelines)